# add Toolbar above UITableView for use in UISplitViewController detail view

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, ipad, uitoolbar, uisplitviewcontroller

I want to use a table view as the detail pane in my UISplitViewController.  How do I put the toolbar at the top?  I want to be able to add bar button items in the same way as my non-table detail views.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My frustration with this problem lay in trying to use the UITableViewController class, which does not allow you to add other UI elements like a toolbar. I solved it by creating a UIViewController object and adding the toolbar and table view to its nib individually.  I then had the ViewController implement the table view's delegate and data source methods.  Works great.

Answer (score 0):

common paradigm is have UINavigationControllers as the top level controllers for master and detail pages.

So the view hiearchy looks like this (loosly speaking)

- Application Window

  - UISplitViewController

    - master : UINavigationController

      - has your custom Controller (tableView or UIView)
    - detail : UINavigationController

      - has your custom controller (UITableViewCOntroller / UIVIEWcontroller)

hope this crude diagram makes sense.

THe perk of having UINavigationController as the top level controller, you get the Toolbar for 'free'.

```
   self.navigationController.toolbar
```

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the UINavigationBar does not allow the addition of BarButtonItems, as I said in my question.

Comment: [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:NO];

This will enable the 'toolbar', which is different from 'navigation bar'

Comment: The setToolbarHidden method dispays the toolbar at the bottom, not the top, and it relies on the view being contained in a UINavigationContoller, which mine is not.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this other way: in case of absense of navigationBar I just add a toolbar at the top of tableView and I change the height for header in first section. The only problem is that toolbar scrolls with the tableView.

Add this to ViewDidLoad of your TableViewController

```
if (! self.navigationController.navigationBar) {
    UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 44)];
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    [self.tableView addSubview:toolBar];
}
```

Add this method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection: (NSInteger)section
{
    return 50;
}
```