# Add toolbar at the bottom of UISplitView based iPad app

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uitoolbar

I have created UISplit view based application. Both, master(root) and detail views are navigation based (UINavigationController). Now I want to add a bar (probably UIToolbar) at the bottom of both views. On this bottom bar I want to keep few buttons like Home, favorites etc.

As of now, nothing is pushed on the root view side. Just to add, RootViewController is inherited from UIViewController with UITableView in it.
But on the detail side, we keep on pushing other views on its navigation controller.

I would like the bottom bar to be visible all the time i.e. when other view controllers are pushed on their respective navigation controllers.

Please suggest how to go about this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a proper answer. But as a workaround, I added UIToolBar at the bottom of each view in xib with same set of bar buttons and provided the same functionality everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

See my [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105304/add-toolbar-above-uitableview-for-use-in-uisplitviewcontroller-detail-view) and adjust to put your UIToolbar at the bottom instead of top.